# Unwanted "Create Procedure queries" is running while SP existed - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

when i get running queries, there is some query of "Create Procedure ..." while stored procedure existed . Most of them are suspended

```
   -- =============================================
   -- Author:       <Author,,Name>
   -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
   -- Description:  <Description,,>
   -- ============================================= 

 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[gps_LastInformation]
    @devSerial int AS 
 BEGIN
   select * from (
    SELECT
     TOP(1) 1 as num,DevSerial as device,'' as alarmcode,' ' as value,
         Latitude as lat, Longitude as lng, Altitude as alt, Speed as speed
    FROM  dbo.GPLSLog
    WHERE DevSerial = @devSerial
    ORDER BY FixTime DESC) as a
   union
   select * from (
    SELECT
     top(1) 2 as num,devSerial as device,alarmCode as alarmcode,'' as value,
          '' as lat, '' as lng, '' as alt, '' as speed
    from alldeviceAlarm 
    where devSerial=@devSerial
      and (alarmCode=1 or alarmCode=2)
    order by fixdate desc) as d     

  END
```

I check SQL profiler, but there is no queries like it. and there is just exec SP

I upgraded Database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012, about two weeks ago.
and user is db_owner

Comment: Whats the actual problem? Do you want to know where these CREATE PROCS are coming from?

Comment: Yes, why it should be there, while they are exist